# ¿Error al instalar paquete en composer(laravel)?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Estoy encontrando un problema demasiado raro, estoy trabajando con laravel 5.2, tengo la versión de php 7.2, cuando hago el comando "composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar:~2.4" me aparece un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Laravel 5.2 no es compatible con php 7.2 o si?

Comment: podria ser eso ya verifique y no es compatible PHP version between 5.5.9 - 7.1.*